# If kinetic energy is scalar why is it defined in different directions?

Tags: kinetic-theory

For a particle with $\frac{1}{2} m v^2$ kinetic energy it's found to be equal to $\frac{3}{2} k_B T$

and in thermal equilibrium 
$\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is given by $$\langle \frac{1}{2}mv_x^2\rangle + \langle\frac{1}{2}mv_y^2\rangle + \langle\frac{1}{2} mv_z^2 \rangle$$

If kinetic energy is scalar why do we specify directions for the velocity?

Comment: In the kinetic model of gases, there is an average amount of $1/2 kT$ energy per degree of freedom. For a free gas particle, with only three translational degrees of freedom, you get the $3/2 k T$. The equation you wrote just says  this explicitly with $x,y,z$ coordinates.

Comment: What do you mean by "specify directions"? By linearity of the expectation value, that's the same as $\frac{1}{2}m\langle \vec v^2\rangle$, with no direction specified. What's the question?

Answer (score 3):

***Short answer***

It's not that the kinetic energy is defined in different directions. It's that we can separate the kinetic energy into the contributions from motion in different directions.

***Long answer***

I'm going to assume you already know the most basic differences between scalars and vectors and how they operate. Obviously, when we deal with a scalar quantity, it would be nonsensical to specify a direction along with its magnitude (e.g. "Dinner tonight will cost $8 east" doesn't make sense), while when dealing with a vector quantity both the magnitude and direction are crucial in fully defining the quantity (e.g. "San Francisco is 350 miles from Los Angeles" could imply that SF is 350 miles underground directly below LA or above LA in the middle to upper layers of the atmosphere since we didn't specify that SF is north of LA, and definitely on *terra firma*).

However, there is a scalar quantity related to vectors that pops up quite often and actually contains some of the directional information found in vectors. It's known as the *scalar product*, or *dot product*, and it is defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for two vectors $\mathbf{a} = a_x \hat{\mathbf{i}} + a_y \hat{\mathbf{j}} + a_z \hat{\mathbf{k}}$ and $\mathbf{b} = b_x \hat{\mathbf{i}} + b_y \hat{\mathbf{j}} + b_z \hat{\mathbf{k}}$ as,

$$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = a_x b_x + a_y b_y + a_z b_z$$

From inspection, we can tell this quantity is in fact a scalar, but notice how not only do the components of each vector appear in the definition, but they're separated in a way such that the individual product of two components in one specific direction (e.g. $a_x b_x$ in the $x$-direction) seems to provide its own independent contribution to the scalar product.

Now that we have defined the scalar product, we can more easily define the kinetic energy of a particle as,

$$K = \frac{1}{2} m \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}$$

where $m$ is its mass and $\mathbf{v}$ is its velocity. Thus, while the kinetic energy $K$ is a scalar quantity, its definition involves the dot product of $\mathbf{v}$ -- a vector -- with itself, and as such we can think of the different components of the velocity vector as each giving a separate contribution to the full value of the kinetic energy,

$$\begin{align} K & = \frac{1}{2} m \left(v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} m v_x^2 + \frac{1}{2} m v_y^2 + \frac{1}{2} m v_z^2 \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

To understand this point, you need to have a clear understanding of the notion of *degree of freedom*. The velocity of a particle is given by three numbers, that are denoted by $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$ here. These three numbers can have independent values. This means that if you know the value of $v_x$, you cannot say anything concerning the values of $v_y$ and $v_z$. It's like in a coordinate system, you need to know the three coordinates to know the exact position of an object. As these numbers are completely independent from each other, we can *freely* chose them. They are called **degrees of freedom**.

*1) One particle*

The norm of the velocity (the speed), is here equal to
$v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$. This is why the kinetic energy of a particle with mass $m$ is $\frac12mv^2=\frac12mv_x^2+\frac12mv_y^2+\frac12mv_z^2$. The kinetic energy is the total energy that you have to give to accelerate a particule at rest to the speed $v_x$ along the $x$-axis **and** to the speed $v_y$ in the $y$-axis **and** to the speed $v_z$ along the $z$ axis. These are degrees of freedom, so you have to give energy to each of them.

*2) Statistical ensemble*

Now, in statistical mechanics, counting always starts with the number of degrees of freedom. The equipartition theorem states that at equilibrium all quadratic energy terms (like $\frac12mv_x^2$) have an average energy of $\frac12k_{\rm B}T$ *per degree of freedom*. Here we have three degrees of freedom *per particle*, so we deduce that the average kinetic energy is $\frac32k_{\rm B}T$ *per particle* : that is an average when we have a large number of particles, a completely different situation !